# Extracting Frame time-stamps from python based NVIDIA's VideoProcessingFramework

Tags: video, video-processing, codec, nvidia-deepstream

I am trying to replace our current video processing library (i.e decord - https://github.com/dmlc/decord ) with NVIDIA's VideoProcessingFramework (VPF) (i.e https://github.com/NVIDIA/VideoProcessingFramework ). Reason why we are using "decord" is because it provides us with each frame's timestamp very accurately. But this decord library is getting very old and not supported, so we want to use NVIDIA's VideoProcessingFramework (VPF), does anyone know how how to extract frame timestamp using VPF. An example piece of code will be very much appreciated.

Regards,
Zavier

........................................................